# Replace agent by 3 others after the process (cutting machine)

Tags: anylogic, agent

i want to model a sawing machine. how can i represent that when agent 1 is processed then it is removed and agent a,b,c is output and when agent 2 is processed then agent x is output 3 times? What blocks do I need and how can I formulate this as code?
I'm a beginner in Anylogic

I tried this with a sink and source Block, but i dont know how i can output 3 agents from a source Block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a source block you can only generate 1 type of agent... and there are 1000 ways to do what you are asking, this is one

What you would need to do is to have enter blocks and generate the agents after the sawing process is done

```
YourAgent1 a=add_YourAgent1();
YourAgent2 b=add_YourAgent2();
YourAgent3 c=add_YourAgent3();

enterBlockA.take(a);
enterBlockB.take(b);
enterBlockC.take(c);
```

you will need to create a population of agents to have access to the function `add_YourAgentTypeName()` that will create a new agent in that population

Then an enter block will act as your source

Comment: First of all, thank you for the fast answer! Should i write this code in the enter Block -> Action -> on enter or where?

Comment: with that question, i think you need to start learning the basics of anylogic.. you are not ready to do anything yet... take my courses they will help at noorjax.teachable.com

Comment: But how do I do it when I have 2 cases of agents?